# Why do I get different responses posting with React and Postman

Tags: reactjs, request, postman, http-post

I have the following function in React that sends a POST to a third-party endpoint:

```
export default function testCfdiApi() {
  const requestString = 'http://some_endpoint/';
  const data =  JSON.stringify({
    User: 'some.user',
    Pass: 'somepassword'
  })

  axios.post(requestString, data)
    .then(Response => {
      alert(Response.data.message)
    })
    .catch(Error => {
      alert(Error)
    })
}
```

And this is the alert I get:

[image]

The problem is that when I send exactly the same POST from postman, I get a different response:

[image]

You can see that the username is returned as part of `Response.message`, but the response I get when I send the POST from React doesn't contain the name. I believe the endpoint is not receiving the form data properly.

I think I am failing to properly configure the request, but I can't find what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Axios [gets the request body as a javascript object](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api), there's no need to serialize it. Try removing the `JSON.stringify` and pass the object directly, it should fix the issue.

Comment: Nope. Actually, I used it that way at the beginning, but the response was an error that I fixed using `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Ok, it may be an encoding problem.  In the postman screenshot you posted, the request body is encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Axios will probably encode the body as a json. You can confirm it checking the network tab of the browser dev tools.

Comment: This is the encoding in the dev tools: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded